# Treeview AfterLabelEdit Keeps Firing?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I have a tree view and it's populated with tow parent nodes, and sub nodes for each parent node. I have added like a template node "Add New" in order to do database insertion, so i add the "OnNodeMouseDoubleClick" event to begin node edit, afer that i call the "AfterlabelEdit" event and do the insertion which is successfull with no problems, but the thing is that it this event keeps firing for the numbers of the sub nodes included on the parent. Is there anything wrong or that how it does work and if so is there any solution ?

Comment: Very unclear, you don't 'call the AfterLabelEdit event' yourself.  Post code.

Comment: If i have took a little time thinking i could have solved before asking, but never the less it will save people the trouble, question have been edited with the answer.

Comment: @yahyakh, you should post your solution as an answer and then accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(e.Node.IsEditing == true)
    {

          //your code here  
          e.CancelEdit = true;
     }
```